# how to show n lines above and below my grep search?

Tags: bash, grep

I checked out the manifest file of k8s, but i want to also see the above n lines of my search.

```
   cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml | grep -i authorization -A4 
        - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
        - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
        - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
        - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
        - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
```

how tod this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-C` you get the context around the match:

```
grep -C4 -i authorization /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

From `grep` man page:

```
   Context Line Control
       -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.
              With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

       -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.
              With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

       -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
              Print  NUM  lines  of  output  context.   Places  a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or
              --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

Answer (score 2):

Append `-B<n>` to your command. Example: `grep -i authorization -A4 -B4`